# Python script handler for Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch, app.yaml

I am writing an app engine application to fetch url content using urlfetch available in google app engine.

however in the app.yaml file, I have a doubt in script handle

I have found that some people use script name as myScript.py while some tutorials use myScript.app

what's the difference between the two uses  ?

Answer (score 2):

The myScript.py was for the 2.5 runtime, the model for invoking apps with 2.7 runtime normally utilises the myScript.app method. Have a look at the age of the tutorials and also what Python runtime they have configured in their app.yaml.